# How to add pre/post save middlewares in Prisma?

Tags: mongoose, prisma

In mongoose there's an option to access the document of a schema, before, and after save, and do whatever with it accessing useful information like which fields have been changed, etc.. Is there a way to do the same with prisma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prisma's Midddleware feature should help you out. The API and use cases have been defined [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/middleware).